# Obfuscate database table names

Tags: sql-server, obfuscation

We're about to undergo a project where we'll be handling highly sensitive data. Apart from encrypting the data I was thinking about obfuscating the table names.

So `tEmployees` would become `t58633B7A` for example. Would this be a useful to add? after all it's about building layers of security/prevention.

P.S. We'll map the obfuscated table names to the real names in our Data Access Layer

Comment: If a programmer named the tables they are probably obufuscated already. :-)

Comment: It's interesting how everyone has focused on a hacker getting into the database, I'm thinking obfuscating would make a sql injection attack a little harder too, errm which I don't plan to allow that to happen anyway

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems entirely superfluous. If an attacker has gained access to the database, then simply not knowing the table name is little protection in the grand scheme of things. You should spend your time, if anything, on better intrusion detection and protection mechanisms.

Comment: +1: Just have to look at foreign keys/etc to see relationships.  If someone has DB account access, you have ***bigger*** problems

Comment: It would be trivial to rename the tables to whatever you want. If you see a column with data like 'Kevin', 'Bill', 'Judith', you're going to immediately guess it's a first name field. Effort is better expended in securing the database and all replicas so as to avoid leaking data in the first place. A lot of people secure the database server but forget to lock down back-up copies as diligently, for example.

Answer (score 7):

Although you will hear over and over again that *security through obscurity* is bad, it does help raise the bar to attack, so long as you keep in mind that it is not a solution.

For your particular case, I would say that the cost of maintaining, debugging, troubleshooting your database will outweigh the benefits from the tiny amount of perceived security.

Answer (score 4):

What a complete waste of time.

Well, not really.....  it does have the feature of scaring away actual talent during interviews, and might get you a mention on TheDailyWTF.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's probably a waste of time. If someone can hack your program enough that is has access to your database, then your screwed anyway and this hacker will figure out your silly obfuscation scheme in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

Try to design database with PowerDesigner. When you design table (Physical Data Model, PDM) there are column name and column code. Enter the column name with Readable field name but for the column code enter with unreadable field name.
For example to create EMPLOYEE (obscured to table_1) with columns :

```
    NAME     CODE     DATA TYPE
    ID       F1       INTEGER
    NAME     F2       VARCHAR(50)
    DOB      F3       DATE
```

Meanwhile in SQLServer create table as usual (you can get the script from Generate Database Menu)

```
CREATE TABLE table_1(
f1 int,
f2 varchar(50),
f3 date);
```

and create view

```
CREATE VIEW EMPLOYEE WITH ENCRYPTION
AS  
SELECT f1 ID,f2 NAME ,f3 DOB 
FROM table_1
```

the clause WITH ENCRYPTION prevent user from peek the sql statement to make up the view.

In the application code use view EMPLOYEE instead of table_1

Example :

```
insert into EMPLOYEE values('1','kevin','1972/11/24'); 
insert into EMPLOYEE values('2','ted sulivan','1969/06/12');
insert into EMPLOYEE values('3','wei meng lee','1974/04/17');

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

and combine it with data encryption (see : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/)

Of course with this technique, the user still can guest table from the view, but the user can't get the table inter relationship with Primary key and foreign key, the view doesn't have the relational information.
But if you completely obfuscate this process do not using view at all, you must code with table information gathered from PDM.
Hope that can help you. Since i have the same problem with you, when database attached to the machine with administrative account, the database is exposed to the user.